# How to open another GUI window, once video is completed in GUI in python tkinter?

Tags: python

The purpose of the below code is to automatically open another window of GUI once video is completed (the length of video is 10 seconds)

I have tried to do this but some how its not working pl. have a look at below code.

```
import tkinter as tk, threading
import imageio
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as font
import os
import re
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

global Image
global image
global Label

video_name = "C:\\Users\\Ray\\Desktop\\Duplicate.mp4" 
video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)

def stream(label):

for image in video.iter_data():
    frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image))
    label.config(image=frame_image)
    label.image = frame_image

 if __name__ == "__main__":

root = tk.Tk()
my_label = tk.Label(root)
my_label.pack()
thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(my_label,))
thread.daemon = 1
thread.start()

ima = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Ray\\Desktop\\July_bill.jpg')
ima = ima.resize((1920,1050), Image.ANTIALIAS)
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ima)
my_lbl = Label(Image = my_img)
my_lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In this code if I remove the image inserting code ( which is ima, my_img lines in code) the video plays smoothly but if i use this code then it does not works it shows the error of "unknown option "-Image"

Can anybody help me in getting this solved it would be great.

Regards,
Ray

Comment: Also, a couple of comments. First, you are importing tkinter twice. Second, you are importing all modules from tkinter, then you import a submodule. This is NOT necessary. It is considered as bad practice to import modules as: from _module_ import *

Comment: @DanielMelendrez Thank you for pointing out my mistakes, do you know any websites or videos where I can more on this GUI creation in tkinter? If you know then pl. share material because I really need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `my_lbl = Label(Image = my_img)` to `my_lbl = Label(image = my_img)`

You can see TK Label options [here](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/tkinter.ttk.html#label-options). As you can see "image" starts with lowercase, in your code, you had "Image" that caused the error.

Full code:

```py
import tkinter as tk, threading
import imageio
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from time import sleep

def stream(label):
    video_name = "C:\\Users\\Ray\\Desktop\\Duplicate.mp4" 
    video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)
    for image in video.iter_data():
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image))
        label.config(image=frame_image)
        label.image = frame_image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_label = tk.Label(root)
    my_label.pack()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(my_label,))
    thread.daemon = 1
    thread.start()
    sleep(10)
    ima = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Ray\\Desktop\\July_bill.jpg')
    ima = ima.resize((1920,1050), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ima)
    my_lbl = Label(image = my_img)
    my_lbl.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I have not tested the video, but the image works well.

Comment: Thank you @Nima for highlighting one cause of its but in this code the image gets loaded behind the video . Its not even waiting to complete the video and then to execute the image calling code.... I want to load automatically another GUI once the video get's completed is this code correct for that?

Comment: You have to put sleep(10) before the image part of your code. In fact your code needs many improvements.

Comment: Thanks once again @Nima I have imported time and written time.sleep(10) above the image code now the program works but video is not showing and after 10 seconds directly the images comes can you pl. help in sorting out? also pl. let me know which other improvements are required so that I can work on it

Comment: Thank you so much @Nima for helping me by rewriting the code the code works very well but it shows one error " AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo' can you pl. help in solving this pl... also I found one thing that video is not playing may be because of sleep (maybe) it directly opens the image after ( 10) to solve this do I need to change my approach (by using two different roots)?

Comment: hey! @Nima Thank you for you code by little bit adjustment It completely worked for me But I need one help it would be great if you can Help me. I need to insert image in the GUI which will work like button to open another frame i tried but it does not works if you can help it would great for me

Comment: There's a good example and full guide available [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-button-in-tkinter).